# How to set FK to all tables in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

I've about 200 tables in SQL Server 2005 database. Almost tables has column name "AAA" which I want to set FK to column A_ID in table tbl_AAA. I want to know, how can I do this in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system view "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" and build up a query which will result in the DDL statement required to carry out the task.

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' 
    + TABLE_NAME
    + ' ADD FOREIGN KEY (' 
    + COLUMN_NAME 
    + ') REFERENCES tbl_AAA(AAA);'
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME = 'AAA' 
    AND TABLE_NAME <> 'tbl_AAA';
```

You can paste the output of this into SSMS and exceute it. I've done this of the top of my head so you may want to check/tweak/correct to suite your needs.

Cheers